# While changing the JS script folder, getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" and "MIME type text/html"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mime-types

I'm using `dialogFx` script with a customized JS named `classie.js`. I've put both `dialogFx` script and the `classie.js` inside a folder and it works perfect. Everything is fine, until I move `classie.js` to another folder.

Path to files looks like:

> sitepath/JS/dialog/dialogFx.js
>
> sitepath/JS/dialog/classie.js

The problem occurs when I move the classie.js to:

> sitepath/JS/classie.js

**or even :**

> sitepath/JS/**somefolder**/classie.js

The error in chrome console is :

```
classie.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):56 Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "sitepath/JS/classie.js".
```

When I checked the line which it refers to (`classie.js:1`), it's the first line of HTML where `<!DOCTYPE html>` starts.

This is how I include scripts in my header of page:

```
<head>
    <script src="JS/dialog/classie.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="JS/dialog/dialogFx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Chances are your server is replying with an error page (served in HTML) when processing your script requests. Use Fiddler or similar to get the whole response so you can determine what's going on.

Comment: Just make sure you change <script src...  according to where you place classie.js  It needs to be relative path to your html file

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, Although I don't know what it is about and how it works, but I will have look at it. 
@Molda dude, I just simply remove `dialog/` and nothing else.